# Spring Integration | Connection pooling with JMS (ActiveMq)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am trying to integrate my application with JMS Queues (using ActiveMQ). 
I have used Spring Integration as the integration component.
We want to have connection pooling. 
Have provided 'maxConcurrentConsumers' as 100 to 'DefaultMessageListenerContainer'.

The issue is, once all the messages have been read from the queue, "Number of Consumers" remains 100 (as shown on the ActiveMq console). 
When we use connection pooling in database (via JNDI), once the connections are no longer required, they are returned to the pool and number of open connections reduces, which is not happening here.

Any pointers to handle this will be of great help.

My code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- Component scan to find all Spring components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.poc.springinteg._7" />

<!--  -->
<bean id="remoteJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" lazy-init="false"> 
    <property name="environment"> 
        <props> 
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.apache.activemq.jndi</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="connectionFactoryNames">DefaultActiveMQConnectionFactory,QueueConnectionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="queue.SendReceiveQueue">org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/JCAAdminObject/SendReceiveQueue</prop>
            <prop key="queue.SendQueue">org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/JCAAdminObject/MDBTransferBeanOutQueue</prop> 
        </props> 
    </property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="remoteConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="remoteJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="QueueConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

   <!-- writing queue  -->
    <bean id="destinationqueue"        
class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
       <constructor-arg index="0">
       <value>OutputQueue_7</value>
       </constructor-arg> 
   </bean>

<int:channel id="outbound"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" 
                                 channel="outbound"
                                 connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory"
                                 destination="destinationqueue" />

   <!-- reading queue  -->
   <bean id="sourceQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>OutputQueue_7</value>
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageListenerContainer"   
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="remoteConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="sourceQueue"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>         
</bean>

<int:channel id="inbound"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" 
                                        channel="inbound"
                                        extract-payload="false" 
                                        container="messageListenerContainer" />


    <int:service-activator input-channel="inbound"
                        output-channel="outbound"
                        ref="messageReader"
                        method="onMessage" />

</beans>


-- Message Reader Class

import javax.jms.JMSException;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("messageReader")
public class MessageReader
{

@ServiceActivator
public void onMessage(Message inboundMessage) {

    System.out.println(" -------Message Read Start--------");

    System.out.println(inboundMessage.getHeaders());

    System.out.println(" -------Message Headers Reading completed--------");

    System.out.println("payload-->" + inboundMessage.getPayload().getClass());
    String payload = inboundMessage.getPayload().toString();
    System.out.println("payload value-->" + payload);


    org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage obj = (org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage)inboundMessage.getPayload();
    System.out.println("Object-->" + obj);

    String var = null;
    try {
        var = obj.getText();
        System.out.println("Datastructure-->" + obj.getText());
    } catch (JMSException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}


---- Message Writer Class

@Component("sendMessage")
public class SendMessage {

@Autowired
private MessageChannel outbound;


public void send(String name)
{
    Entity entity = new Entity(1,"anuj");

    Message<Entity> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(entity)
                                .setHeader("Message_Header1", "Message_Header1_Value")
                                .setHeader("Message_Header2", "Message_Header2_Value")
                                .build();

    outbound.send(message);
}

}


-- Application main class
public class App {

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:7_applicationContext.xml" );

    SendMessage sendMessage = (SendMessage)applicationContext.getBean( "sendMessage", SendMessage.class);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        sendMessage.send("This is Message Content");
    }

    applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
}

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the connection factory in a `CachingConnectionFactory` there will be one connection shared by all the consumers.

The consumers will be adjusted by the container between `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers` based on demand; after a burst of activity it will take some time before the consumers are reduced.